# one record from each group?

Tags: sql, group-by

Say I have a table like this:

```
x1 | y1 | x2 | y2 | area | color 

 5 |  0 |  5 |  0 |    1 | r
 5 |  0 |  6 |  0 |    2 | g
 5 |  1 |  5 |  0 |    2 | b
 5 |  1 |  5 |  1 |    2 | r
 5 |  2 |  5 |  0 |    3 | g
 5 |  2 |  5 |  1 |    3 | b
```

How can I construct an SQL query so that the resulting table has *one* of r, g, b (each having the maximum area), but also *preserving* the coordinates of this record? I tried MAX(AREA) and GROUP BY color, but that gives me records with maximum area for r, g, b but not together with their coordinates.

I am using PostgreSQL Sample output (for the one above), should be something like:

```
 5 |  1 |  5 |  1 |    2 | r
 5 |  2 |  5 |  0 |    3 | g
 5 |  2 |  5 |  1 |    3 | b
```

Basically it should return 4th, 5th, and 6th record.

Comment: can you show a sample of the output you'd want?

Comment: Can you provide a sample output from this query?  I'm having a little trouble understanding it.

Comment: Not clear what you're after.  By "the maximum area" you mean the maximum area for all colors, or for one particular color?

Comment: What do you want to happen when there are multiple records with the same (maximum) area? Return all of them, or just one of them? If the latter, which one? Any one?

Comment: Do you have a PK or anything at all which can be used to uniquely identify a row?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL 
Sample output (for the one above), should be something like:

x1 | y1 | x2 | y2 | area | color 

5 | 1 | 5 | 1 |    2 | r

5 | 2 | 5 | 0 |    3 | g

5 | 2 | 5 | 1 |    3 | b

5 | 0 | 5 | 0 |    1 | r

5 | 0 | 6 | 0 |    2 | g

5 | 1 | 5 | 0 |    2 | b
5 | 1 | 5 | 1 |    1 | r
5 | 2 | 5 | 0 |    3 | g
5 | 2 | 5 | 1 |    2 | b

Mark: return all of them.

Comment: Err... basically it should return 4th, 5th, and 6th record.

Comment: @Nick, you can edit the question you ask to add details and answer questions, instead of a comment. Easier to format that way.

Comment: And new comment, since I can't edit: What is the desired output in the case of ties for max area?

Comment: What's the name of your table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but I guess you want this:

```
SELECT T2.* FROM (
    SELECT color, max(area) AS area
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY color) AS T1
JOIN table1 AS T2
ON T1.area = T2.area AND T1.color = T2.color
```

Note that it assumes that the maximum area is unique, otherwise you will get multiple rows.

Output for your data:

```
x1 | x2 | y1 | y2 | area | color
 5 |  1 |  5 |  1 |    2 |     r
 5 |  2 |  5 |  0 |    3 |     g
 5 |  2 |  5 |  1 |    3 |     b
```

If you want a better answer, please clarify all the questions I have posted as comments (some of them are hidden).

Comment: This is the right answer given the described table, but joining the derived table on a unique primary key is better practice.  What happens when multiple 'r' rows have the same area, but different data elsewhere in the row?

Comment: @Michael, You're of course right that you should use a PK. I asked in a comment if he even has a primary key, but he hasn't replied yet. Therefore I will assume that he doesn't have a PK until told otherwise. Unfortunately many of my comments asking for clarification have been hidden :(

Comment: No worries.  My comment's directed more at the OP, and anyone viewing this in the future.

Comment: @OMG Poines: actually I meant ON not WHERE - I just typed the wrong thing somehow. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, max(area), color from T group by color;
```